# Get a variable from a different class

Tags: java

So I'm trying to cut back on some of the code that's been written. I created a separate class to try this. I have that class working correctly, however the old one uses variables that are now in the separate class. How do I access these variables? Unfortunately I can't share all the code for this, but I can give out small pieces that I think are necessary. Thanks for the help

This is from the old class that I am now trying to bring the variable to:  I'm trying to bring "loader" over

```
// XComponentLoader loader = null;

fixture.execute(new OpenOfficeOpener());
component = loader.loadComponentFromURL("file:///"+System.getenv("BONDER_ROOT") + "/ControlledFiles/CommonFiles/"+spreadsheet, "_blank", 0, loadProps);
```

Comment: It depends on how loader and other class defined. Provide more details about other class and loader variable.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit? I don't quite get what you mean, but accessing a field of class  `A` from class `B` is fairly trivial (normally by calling a getter). So where's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can write getters for the members that you need to be visible outside. Example:

```
public class MyClass {
     private int member1;
     private String member2;

     public int getMember1() { 
         return member1;
     }

     public String getMember2() { 
         return member2;
     }
}
```

Now both `member1` and `member2` can be accessed from the outside.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of solutions to your problem. What I would suggest is to add a method in your class to return the value to the new program, or pass it as a parameter.
An example of this on a higher level might look like this:

`x = newClass.getValX()`

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for a static field, though if is the case you almost certainly reconsider your current design.

```
public class YourClass {

    private static XComponentLoader loader;

    public YourClass() {
       YourClass.loader = new XComponentLoader();
    }


}
```

And to access it from another class:

```
public YourOtherClass {
    public void yourMethod() {
        YourClass.loader ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `loader` is static, than do something like:

```
component = TheOtherClass.loader.loadComponentFromURL( ...
```

Otherwise, your new class needs a reference to an instance of the other class. You could pass it with the constructor:

```
public class NewClass {

    private OldClass oldClass = null;
    public NewClass(OldClass oldClass) {
       this.oldClass = oldClass;
    }

    // ...

       fixture.execute(new OpenOfficeOpener());
       // assuming, loader is a public field on OldClass.
       // a getter (getLoader()) is preferred
       component = oldClass.loader.loadComponentFromURL("file:///"+System.getenv("BONDER_ROOT") + "/ControlledFiles/CommonFiles/"+spreadsheet, "_blank", 0, loadProps);

   // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've you've split functionality into two classes, then you may want to have one class instantiate another.

If you've put your new code in Class B then it might look like this.

```
public class A {
    // Class B instance
    B b = new B();

    public void doSomething() {
        b.loadComponentFromURL("someurl");
    }
}
```

Or if the loader is an instance itself, you could call it like this.

```
b.getLoader().loadComponentFromURL("someurl");
```